# Eclipse Egit: can one specify the checkout location of branches?

Tags: eclipse, git

Is it possible to choose/adjust a branch's checkout-location in Egit (Eclipse's Git implementation)?
I would like to keep my local git repositories in one location and my workspace in a different one (mainly for backup reasons). 
Right now, Egit always checks out to the parent-folder of the .git folder. I would prefer to keep these directories strictly separated, i.e.

```
.../some-place/foo/.git  (local git repo)
.../some-other-place/workspace/*  (checked out projects go here)
```

Furthermore, for a specific project I would like to check out projects from different repositories into the same workspace. Is that possible with Egit?

```
.../some-place/foo/.git (local repo1)
.../some-place/bar/.git (local repo2)
.../some-other-place/workspace/*  (projects from repo1 AND repo2 go here).
```

In an alternate setup I would occasionally like to checkout different branches to different locations (i.e. different workspaces). Is that possible?

Comment: To make it clear. You want to have the `.git` folder of the project in some other folder? *for backup reasons* - You push your code somewhere, right?

Comment: Well - backup is probably not the right word or misleading. I regularly shuttle my workspace between two systems. For that I would prefer to shuttle really the workspace only but without the git repos.

Comment: I had posted a similar question in the Eclipse Egit forum and was made aware of this most interesting page: https://rakhesh.com/coding/how-to-move-separate-the-git-folder-out-of-your-working-tree/. So, it obviously *is* possible to separate repo and workspace. What is still missing is the possibility to have the files from 2 repos in a common workspace.